# Php counter that never fails

Tags: php, counter

I managed to make this PHP counter without database, it is very basic as it increments the visits in a .txt file:

```
$counter_file = ("count.txt");
$fp = fopen($counter_file, "r");
$count = fread($fp, 1024);
fclose($fp);
$count = $count +1;
$fp = fopen($counter_file, "w");
fwrite($fp, $count);
fclose($fp);
```

But this counter fails on a distant server, when the visits are too fast. It goes back to 0.
What can explain this behaviour and how to make sure the counter will never go back to 0?

**Edit**: This script seams to be more robust. It uses `flock` as @ghopst suggested.

```
$counter_file = ("count.txt");
$handle = fopen($counter_file,"r+");

//Lock File, error if unable to lock
if(flock($handle, LOCK_EX)) {
    $count = fread($handle, filesize($counter_file));
    $count = $count + 1;
    ftruncate($handle, 0);
    rewind($handle);
    fwrite($handle, $count);
    flock($handle, LOCK_UN);
} else {
    echo "Could not Lock File!";
}
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: To prevent it from resetting, lock the file while writing to avoid concurrent writes. You can use `flock`

Comment: `file_put_contents('count.txt', (int)file_get_contents('count.txt') + 1;` is way shorter. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's down to the file system, your code makes a request to open, read, close, open, write and close the file for each visitor. If the file is being written it is locked against being written to by another instance, it's a behavior of the file system. Perhaps it would be better to have a simple database table with a autoincrement column and just insert a row for each visit then delete it , then you could just select the top row to return a value.

Answer (score -1):

Try this version:

```
<?php

    $counter_file = ("count.txt");
    $count = @file_get_contents($counter_file);
    $count = $count ? intval($count) + 1 : 1;
    file_put_contents($counter_file, $count);
```